# Wordpress on Windows with ASP.NET application behind it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, web-applications, content-management-system

I am starting to build a web application and am using ASP.NET MVC.  I'm more of a back end programmer and figured that I would use Wordpress for the 'brochureware' in front of the login.  There are other, more Windows friendly CMSs but I'm most familiar with Wordpress and would prefer to spend time on the actual app.  I'm looking for anyone who has done this that might have a recommended approach (or pitfalls to avoid).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[N2CMS](http://n2cms.com/) is always a nice option to go with MVC. It works as more of a component than the dominant feature.

Comment: The site is down at the mo sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a CMS that runs on ASP.NET like Orchard or Umbraco (I prefer the later). They're very easy to setup and both use Razor Views for rendering content. If you have a Windows Azure subscription you can setup the site in less than 5 minutes.

The great thing about this approach is that you can have the user logged on both apps using the same authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I could simply run WordPress from an Azure instance, and from the same domain (if desired), run my .NET application.  Problem solved!